# Vehicle travel data for the USA

Tags: data, transportation

I'm looking for vehicle travel data in the USA - at any spatial resolution smaller than the unit of a state, and ideally at a city level. I'm interested in daily, or weekly data and also any information about whether the trip is to work or not.

Two sources that I have previously found are the Texas Transportation Institute [Urban Mobility Report](http://mobility.tamu.edu/ums/), and vehicle miles traveled at a 250m gridcell for Massachusetts from the MAPC [link](http://geonode.mapc.org/data/MAPC%3avmt_250m_grid) (data is available, but site currently has a problem)

I've looked at the Federal Highway Administration [FHWA](http://www.fhwa.dot.gov/) site which has a special [GIS](http://www.gis.fhwa.dot.gov/fhwaEfforts.asp) section, but I'm struggling to find data on the site outside of reports in the form of pdfs.

Are there any other sources of data that are available that I have overlooked?

Comment: Are you looking for AADT or hourly data and in how many vehicle class bins? Also historical or live?

Comment: Ah, good points - just updated my question.

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't gotten back to you. Did you find the data you were looking for?

Answer (score 4):

The [National Highway Travel Survey collects](http://nhts.ornl.gov) the trip information you're looking for and can be found [here](http://nhts.ornl.gov/download.shtml) for all the US.

First I would start looking at the [FHWA planning data warehouse](http://www.fhwa.dot.gov/resourcecenter/teams/planning/data.cfm). If that doesn't help, you have a few options:

1. Contact the major state and urban DOT / MTO and they'll usually give you the data you're looking for. This option yields the most accurate and up to date data; however you want your data to match the survey data. Actually for a number of the states, they have their traffic data online.
2. Obtain a copy of TransCAD - Traffic Data. TransCAD is a software used by transportation modellers. With the software package comes a cd that has traffic counts for the US.
3. [The Bureau of Transportation statistics](http://bts.gov) contains transportation data related to entry points into the US, intermodal activities, and other related data
4. The NAtional Highway Transportation Safety Administration provides some data too. [NASS General Data](http://www.nhtsa.gov/NASS) and [Traffic Records](http://www.nhtsa.gov/Data/Traffic+Records)

Comment: I also have a lot more resources than this. Start up here, if that doesn't get you anywhere, comment on this with what you're missing and I shall see what I can do

Comment: Thanks - just reading through the links. Can the NHTS be easily related to tracts? If estimates of total distances are given I could just aggregate to each city I am interested in.

Comment: I haven't worked with NHTS in 8 years or so. I'll check for you at the office on Monday and see if I can track down older projects

Comment: I was wondering, were you able to get the data you needed?

Comment: I wasn't able to find it - I used the Texas data as a temporary measure, but I am still interested in a high resolution measure of traffic data. Thanks for following up.